# Excel running macro on current sheet even though code specifies otherwise

Tags: vba, excel, macros, autofilter

I have the following code:

```
Sheets("Booked").Range("$A$1:$H$379").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:= _
        ">=" & StartDat
Sheets("Booked").Range("$A$1:$H$379").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:= _
        "<=" & EndDat
CorBookCol = Worksheets("Booked").Cells.Find("Booked Impressions").Address

BookAnswer = Worksheets("Booked").Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(9, Range(CorBookCol, Range(CorBookCol).End(xlDown)))
MsgBox (BookAnswer)
Debug.Print "------------------"
Debug.Print BookAnswer & " - Booked Answer"
```

The goal is to have the macro acquire the sub total of a column from my "Booked" worksheet and use that number in conjunction with other numbers from my current sheet. However, even though I have specified that the macro find the sub total from the "Booked" worksheet, it will only find the subtotal of the "BookedCorCol" address on my current sheet. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You need to fully qualify your Range. Do you see the `.` (Dots) before the Range object? If you do not do that then the range will refer to the `ActiveSheet`

```
With Worksheets("Booked")
    BookAnswer = .Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(9, _
                 .Range(CorBookCol, .Range(CorBookCol).End(xlDown)))
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to qualify the two `Range` calls that you pass to the Subtotal function.

```
With Sheets("Booked")
   .Range("$A$1:$H$379").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=">=" & StartDat
   .Range("$A$1:$H$379").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="<=" & EndDat
   CorBookCol = .Cells.Find("Booked Impressions").Address

    BookAnswer = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(9, .Range(CorBookCol, .Range(CorBookCol).End(xlDown)))
End With
MsgBox (BookAnswer)
Debug.Print "------------------"
Debug.Print BookAnswer & " - Booked Answer"
```